# Filter out Array of object by a give value and avoiding to add duplicated according to the same value

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I am trying to figure out how to extract a new array of object from an existing one according to some conditions I am passing through PLUS don't copy over the new array if the element already exist.

So this is the object I have: [addressesObj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaHhL.png)

Now I would like to filter the object by a given postcode for instance:

```
`
 var PostCode = "TN37 7AJ  "
 var newAddressesObj =  addressesObj.filter( function (duties) {
      return duties.Address.Postcode === PostCode
     });
`
```

This works correctly, it gives me back an array with 2 objects:

[newAddressesObj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akK0J.png)

Now from this new array I would like to delete the records with the same Postcode so it gives me back only one object - how do I do that?

I have tried using $.inArray together with the filter but I am doing something wrong, I also would like to do that all in one go - something like this:

`var PostCode = "TN37 7AJ  "
 var newAddressesObj =  addressesObj.filter( function (duties) {
   return duties.Address.Postcode === PostCode && $.inArray(PostCode, addressesObj == -1
      });`

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control) instead of `filter`. `find` stops after the first match.

Comment: Oh, I get it. You want to extract all distinct objects that have a specific postal code.

Comment: I forgot to mention something on my question...in reality from that object I want to extract 2 element and not one.
This is the real implementation:
     var StartPCode = "TN37 7AJ", EndPCode = "TN38 8EW"
     var newAddressesObj =  addressesObj.filter( function (x) {
         return (x.Address.StartPCode === StartPCode || x.Address.EndtPcode === EndPCode) && $.inArray(PCode, addressesObj == -1 });

At the end I would like an object with 2 element inside with diff postcode so I can pass to google Maps and show the route basically...

Thanks anyway for your quick replay tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the filtered postcode into an array and keep checking the postcode array for each element looped.

```
var PostCode = "TN37 7AJ";
var addressesObj = [{
        "Address": {
            "Postcode": "TN38 8EW",
            "AddressLine1": "32 Head View"
        },
        "Name": "Ball, Jones",
        "ServiceDutyId": 0
    },
    {
        "Address": {
            "Postcode": "TN37 7AJ",
            "AddressLine1": "171 Road"
        },
        "Name": "Trump, Albert",
        "ServiceDutyId": 3259
    },
    {
        "Address": {
            "Postcode": "BN1 5AA",
            "AddressLine1": "171 Road"
        },
        "Name": "Martin, Lucas",
        "ServiceDutyId": 4256
    },
    {
        "Address": {
            "Postcode": "TN37 7AJ",
            "AddressLine1": "171 Road"
        },
        "Name": "Trump Albert",
        "ServiceDutyId": 3273
    }
]

var postcodeArr = [];

var isAbsence = function(postcode) {
    if (postcodeArr.indexOf(postcode) == -1) {
        postcodeArr.push(postcode);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var newAddressesObj = addressesObj.filter(function(duties) {
    return duties.Address.Postcode === PostCode && isAbsence(duties.Address.Postcode);
});
```